# ListView in adapter of another ListView is calling getView for every view

Tags: android, listview

I have the following class:

```
public class AssociadosSituacaoVO implements Comparable<AssociadosSituacaoVO>{
    private String situacao;
    private ArrayList<AssociadoVO> associados;
    public String getSituacao() {return situacao;}
    public void setSituacao(String situacao) {this.situacao = situacao;}    
    public ArrayList<AssociadoVO> getAssociados() {return associados;}
    public void addAssociado(AssociadoVO associado){associados.add(associado);}
    public void setAssociados(ArrayList<AssociadoVO> associados) {this.associados = associados;}
    @Override
    public int compareTo(AssociadosSituacaoVO another) {return Utilidades.compareToLongLower(getOrder(), another.getOrder());}
}
```

and this class have the following adapter:

```
public class AdapterListViewListaAssociados extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<AssociadosSituacaoVO> itens;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<AdapterListViewAssociados> adapters;
public AdapterListViewListaAssociados(Context context, List<AssociadosSituacaoVO> itens) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itens = itens;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    adapters = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.sort(itens);
}
public void setItens(List<AssociadosSituacaoVO> itens) {
    this.itens = itens;
    Collections.sort(itens);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public void clearData() {
    itens.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public int getCount() {
    return itens.size();
}
public AssociadosSituacaoVO getItem(int position) {
    return itens.get(position);
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.i("MyInfo", "AdapterListViewListaAssociados.getView(" + position + ");");
    final AssociadosSituacaoVO item = itens.get(position);
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewitem_associados_lista, null);
    final TextView tvListaNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvListaNome);
    final ListView listViewLista = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewListaAssociados);
    tvListaNome.setText(item.getSituacao());
    if (adapters.size() - 1 < position) {
        Log.i("MyInfo", "if   (" + (adapters.size() - 1) + " < " + position + ")");
        adapters.add(new AdapterListViewAssociados(context, item.getAssociados(), true));
        listViewLista.setAdapter(adapters.get(position));
        listViewLista.setOnItemClickListener(click);
        Utilidades.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listViewLista);
    } else {
        Log.i("MyInfo", "else (" + (adapters.size() - 1) + " < " + position + ")");
        listViewLista.setAdapter(adapters.get(position));
        listViewLista.setOnItemClickListener(click);
        Utilidades.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listViewLista);
    }

    return view;
}

ListView.OnItemClickListener click = new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (AppUserAtualVO.iduser == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Você precisa estar logado para acessar informações desse associado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (AppUserAtualVO.pverdadosassociados == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Você não tem permissão para acessar essas informações.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            AssociadoVO item = adapters.get(position).getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AssociadoActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("associado", item);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
};
}
```

The method Utilidades.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView):

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null)
        return;

    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int totalHeight = 0;
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
        if (i == 0)
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

listviewitem_associado_lista.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" //(also tried wrap)
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvListaNome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimarySoft"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listViewListaAssociados" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Result:
Once the AdapterListViewListaAssociados calls the method getView(), it creates the adapter for the itens in the child list view (listViewListaAssociados) if it doesnt exist, and then, when it calls the views from the child list view, it calls EVERY view, not the ones that appear in screen but all.

Log:

```
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewListaAssociados.getView(0);
I/MyInfo: if   (-1 < 0)
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(0);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(1);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(2);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(3);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(4);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(5);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(6);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(7);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(8);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(9);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(10);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(11);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(12);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(13);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(14);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(15);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(16);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(17);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(0);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(1);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(2);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(3);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(4);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(5);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(6);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(7);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(8);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(9);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(10);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(11);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(12);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(13);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(14);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(15);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(16);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(17);
```

and then i scroll to the bottom:

```
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewListaAssociados.getView(2);
I/MyInfo: if   (1 < 2)
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(0);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(1);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(2);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(3);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(4);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(0);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(1);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(2);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(3);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(4);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewListaAssociados.getView(3);
I/MyInfo: if   (2 < 3)
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(0);
I/MyInfo: AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(0);
```

The problem:

Once the child listview get all views when appears, it takes a little bit to load.
Is it caused by the use of Utilidades.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView): ? i tried without it but it shows only 1-2 views...

How can i make to the child listview use getView only in the used views ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve it but I realize the method Utilidades.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView) was making it calls every view in the child list view...

So I created a class that extends AssociadoVO that have the header/section name (that was the point, I was trying to create a header, so every AssociadosSituacaoVO had a situacao that was the header, after that I used only 1 list view that uses the AdapterListViewAssociados and in this I have this code in the getView method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.i("MyInfo", "AdapterListViewAssociados.getView(" + position + ");");
    final AssociadoVO item = itens.get(position);
    if (item instanceof SituacaoVO) {
        SituacaoVO situacao = (SituacaoVO) item;
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewitem_associados_header, null);
        TextView tvListaNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvListaNome);
        tvListaNome.setText(situacao.getNomeSituacao());
    }else{
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewitem_associado, null);
        // deal with the normal layout of AssociadoVO...
    }
    return view;
}
```

I'm new in android developing, but I'm happy that I could figure this.

Hope this helps someone else one day.